# How do I merge two videos and increase sound volume using Avconv?

Tags: libav

I'm trying to merge two cd-s into 1 file and also boost sound volume 200%, I tried this using avconv tool, but I only got cd1 and without an boost in sound:

```
nohup avconv -i cd1.avi -i cd2.avi -vcodec libx264 -acodec libvo_aacenc -r 30000/1001 -vol 512 merged.mp4
```

I used same syntax as for ffmpeg, any ideas why it didn't work? I can't find documentation for -vol for avconv. and also info about merging files is scarce.

Comment: Please show your ffmpeg command and the complete ffmpeg console output.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I don't have ffmpeg anymore, it was replaced by avconv on ubuntu. So I figured both tools have same devs and they are same software essentially, I used ffmpeg flags.

Comment: Both tools do not have the same developers and there are differences. See [Who can tell me the difference and relation between ffmpeg, libav, and avconv?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9477756/1109017)

Answer (score 0):

avconv does not support concatentation (yet, patches welcome). The ways to work around this are e.g.

- use mplayer(2) with `-vo yuv4mpeg` to decode your two video into a pipe, make avconv read from this pipe.
- encode the two videos separately, then use mkvmerge to merge them.